# How to open native GoogleMaps App & Waze App

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift3, waze

I want to open directions driving mode in both GoogleMaps & Waze in native app. How to do it?

```
func showActionSheet(vc: UIViewController) {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Google Maps", style: .default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.openGoogleMaps()
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Waze", style: .default, handler: { (alert:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.openWaze()
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    vc.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Currently I've implement 2 functions, but I would like to know how to open in native apps for both maps

```
    func openGoogleMaps() {
//Don't want open in URL, want to open in native googlemaps app
        }

   func openWaze() {
  //Don't want open in URL, want to open in native Waze app
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check Waze or Google map apps are available or not on user's phone.
After that, you can open Waze/Google app from your app with URL Scheeme.

```
func openGoogleMaps() {
   if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {  //First check Google Mpas installed on User's phone or not.
           UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic")!) //It will open native google maps app.
   } else {
           print("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
    }
}


func openWaze() {
  if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"waze://")!)) {  //First check Waze Mpas installed on User's phone or not.
       UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "waze://")!) //It will open native wazw maps app.
   } else {
           print("Can't use waze://");
   }
}
```

When compiling with iOS SDK 9.0 and later, you must update your application's property list file with the following to include Waze:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>waze</string>
</array>
```